# Как правильно обрезать изображение лица, полученного в openCV, с отступами?

Tags: python, python-3.x, изображения, opencv, обработка-изображений

Имею такие данные: x/y центра лица, высота и ширина лица , высота и ширина исходного изображения. Пользователь загружает изображения, где лицо может быть в совершено разных местах, и соотношения сторон у изображения может быть разным

определяю есть ли лицо с помощью openCV:

```
def crop_face(img, margin_x = 550, margin_y = 400):
image = cv2.imread(img)
height, width = image.shape[:2]
#print('width - {0}, height - {1}'.format(width, height))
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(FACE_DETECTOR_PATH)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.29, 5)
print ("Found {0} faces!".format(len(faces)))
if len(faces) == 1:     
for (x,y,w,h) in faces:                 
    r = max(w, h) / 2
    centerx = x + w / 2
    centery = y + h / 2
    nx = int(centerx - r)
    ny = int(centery - r)
    nr = int(r * 2)
    print ('x - {0}, y - {1}, w - {2}, h - {3}'.format(x,y,w,h))
    print ('r - {0}, centerX - {1}, centerY - {2}, nx - {3}, ny - {4},nr - {5}'.format(r,centerx,centery,nx,ny, nr))
    margin_dict = get_normal_margin(margin_x, margin_y ,centerx, centery, height,width)
    margin_dict['x_max'] -= int(w/2);
    margin_dict['x_min'] -= int(w/2);
    margin_dict['y_max'] -= int(h/2);
    margin_dict['y_min'] -= int(h/2);
    roi_color = image[y-margin_dict['y_min']:y + h+margin_dict['y_max'], x-margin_dict['x_min']:x + w +margin_dict['x_max']]#y max, y min, x max, x min
    #roi_color = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    return roi_color
```

так пытаюсь получить предельный допустимый отступ для x и y:

```
def get_normal_margin(margin_x, margin_y, center_x, center_y, height, width):
margin_to_return = {'y_max': margin_y, 'y_min': margin_y, 'x_max': margin_x, 
'x_min': margin_x}
for x in range(int(center_x),  width - int(center_x)):      
if(x < margin_x and x > 0):
    margin_to_return['x_max'] = x           
for x in reversed(range(int(center_x),  width - int(center_x))):
if(x < margin_x and x > 0):     
    margin_to_return['x_min'] = x
for x in range(int(center_y),  height - int(center_y)):     
if(x < margin_y and x > 0):
        margin_to_return['y_max'] = x
for x in reversed(range(int(center_y),  height - int(center_y))):
if(x < margin_y and x > 0):
    margin_to_return['y_min'] = x           
return margin_to_return
```

Но не получается. Некоторые изображения обрезает нормально, некоторые совсем ненормально
Вот примеры:
[даю на вход](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJd4Z.jpg), [получаю на выход](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVY7n.jpg).
Я на правильном пути или вообще не то делаю? 
Пытаюсь сделать, чтобы [было так](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nv9ql.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
def crop_face(img, target_size=(500, 400), debug=False,
              scaleFactor=1.25,
              face_detector_path=FACE_DETECTOR_PATH):
    face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(FACE_DETECTOR_PATH)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor, 5)
    max_y, max_x = img.shape[:2]            # get maximum image coordinates
    tgt_width, tgt_height = target_size     # set target width & height
    if len(faces) == 0:
        return None
    x,y,w,h = faces[0]      # consider only the first face that was found
    delta_x, delta_y = (tgt_width - w) // 2, (tgt_height - h) // 2
    x0, x1 = max(0, x-delta_x), min(x+w+delta_x, max_x)
    y0, y1 = max(0, y-delta_y), min(y+h+delta_y, max_y)
    if debug:
        print(f"x0:\t{x0}\ty0:\t{y0}")
        print(f"x1:\t{x1}\ty1:\t{y1}")
    return  img[y0:y1, x0:x1]

fn = r'D:\download\img4.jpg'
img = cv2.imread(fn)
face = crop_face(img, (500, 400))
#cv2.imshow('new', face)
cv2.imwrite(fn.replace('.jpg', '_res.jpg'), face)
```

результаты для ваших картинок:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: работает намного лучше, чем у меня, но все же не идеально. Первые два и последнее нормально(499x399 и 500x400 и 499x399), а третье изображение 500x399. Да 1px - ничего страшного, но вот если загрузить [такую](https://imgur.com/a/Rf6naIJ) картинку - будет 454x399

Comment: @xomem, а что вы хотите получить из данной фотографии? Один размер все равно __в общем__ случае получить не получится - например как вы будете обрезать фото размерности 400x600 до размерности 500x400 ?

Comment: сделать 300x200

Comment: @xomem, т.е. для вас главным критерием является соотношение сторон?

Comment: да, так как потом будет выгрузка на html страницу, в блок с фиксированной шириной/высотой

Answer (score 1):

вот еще один вариант, который сохраняет соотношения сторон:

```
def crop_face(img, target_size=(500, 400), debug=False,
              scaleFactor=1.25,
              face_detector_path=FACE_DETECTOR_PATH):
    face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(FACE_DETECTOR_PATH)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor, 5)
    max_y, max_x = img.shape[:2]            # get maximum image coordinates
    tgt_width, tgt_height = target_size     # set target width & height
    if len(faces) == 0:
        return None
    x,y,w,h = faces[0]      # consider only the first face that was found
    delta_x, delta_y = (tgt_width - w) // 2, (tgt_height - h) // 2
    x0, x1 = max(0, x-delta_x), min(x+w+delta_x, max_x)
    y0, y1 = max(0, y-delta_y), min(y+h+delta_y, max_y)
    if debug:
        print(f"Top left:\t({x0}, {y0})\nBottom right:\t({x1}, {y1})")
    return  img[y0:y1, x0:x1]


def adjust_aspect_ratio(img, target_size=(500, 400)):
    max_y, max_x = img.shape[:2]            # get maximum image coordinates
    tgt_width, tgt_height = target_size     # set target width & height
    ratio = tgt_width / tgt_height
    delta_x, delta_y = (tgt_width - max_x) // 2, (tgt_height - max_y) // 2
    if max(delta_x, delta_y) < 3:           # no need to adjust margins
        return img
    if delta_x > delta_y:
        tgt_height = int(round(w / ratio))
        delta_y = abs(tgt_height - h) // 2
        print(f"adjusting Y coordinates: ({y + delta_y} : {max_y - delta_y})")
        return img[delta_y : max_y - delta_y, :]
    if delta_x < delta_y:
        tgt_width = int(round(h / ratio))
        delta_x = abs(tgt_width - h) // 2
        print(f"adjusting X coordinates: ({x + delta_x} : {max_x - delta_x})")
        return img[:, delta_x : max_x - delta_x]
    return img


target_size=(500, 400)
img = cv2.imread(fn)
face = crop_face(img, target_size=target_size)
face2 = adjust_aspect_ratio(face, target_size=target_size)
cv2.imshow('face2', face2)
print(f"Image shape: {face2.shape}")
print(f"Target aspect ratio: {target_size[0] / target_size[1]}")
print(f"Actual aspect ratio: {face2.shape[1] / face2.shape[0]}")
```

Вывод:

```
adjusting Y coordinates: (172 : 381)
Image shape: (363, 454, 3)
Target aspect ratio: 1.25
Actual aspect ratio: 1.2506887052341598
```